# Styling a div based on the flex wrap property using javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

A created a function that renders buttons depending on how many data gotten from database.

I want to use js  to set the style the button container differently,

especially setting property of of the button container to flex direction to column when it starts wrapping,

Since the website can have  many buttons.

Is there a way to use javascript to check for the flexwrap property of the button container.

I tried this code but it is returning an empty string
Console.log (btnContainer.style.flexWrap)

Comment: use getComputedStyle()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

try running *btnContainer.style* in the console directly, rather than console.log(). hope it will help you find a solution

Comment: I did and it returned the list of all css style which are all = '' ''

Answer (score 0):

This commend check only inline style like `<div style="flex-wrap:wrap;"></div>`. Now if you `console.log(document.querySelector('div').style.flexWrap)` you will get string with value "wrap".

The solution your problem is add style this element in html inline as I wrote above or in js like `document.querySelector('div').style.flexWrap = wrap`